# Parsing json with newline character and displaying as HTML

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON blob and it has a new line character which is in the escaped form. I want to parse the JSON blob with the newline character and display it as a HTML paragraph in React.

Is that possible?

Code:

```
var Blob = [{ "Content" : "HEHkspodjoisndjdsnsd \\n New Line here you go"}]
var TestClass = React.createClass({
    render:function() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.test.Content}</div>
        );
    }
});

<TestClass test={Blob} />, document.getElementById('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

This library would render your content very nicely using markup - it recognizes \n as a paragraph break - and you could even further create more markdown in your JSON blob to more deeply customize the display.

https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown